# Trying to understand the inheritance rule between policy files

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Trying to understand the inheritance between policy files provides in starter packs.

In xml files we have an element like this:

```
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_<NAME OF THE PARENT POLICY></PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
```

Is it safe to assume that I can override **everything** in the base policy by copy/pasting its xml definition with the **same ID** and start to modifying it?

If the answer is yes, is there any exception to the above rule, means some of the XML definitions in the parent policy cannot be overridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - think of it as a merge.

If you override e.g. a Technical Profile and add an extension attribute e.g.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
...
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_newAttribute"/>
```

it will add the attribute to the TP and read it.

If you change a value e.g.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
...
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource"          DefaultValue="newAuthentication"/>
```

the value will be updated.

But if you delete a row e.g.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
...
<!-- This line deleted in override -->
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName"/>
```

the claim will not be deleted and still be read.

For this case, you have to define a new TP.

I haven't come across any instances that can't be overwritten.